# how can I start laravel artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel and trying to start a PHP artisan server but I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\Users\Admin\Budget\bootstrap\app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\Admin\Budget\artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\Admin\Budget\bootstrap\app.php on line 14
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: ran composer install?

Comment: I already did, but no change still

Comment: @HillaryOkello Are you  still having issue ?

Comment: Yes I ran composer update --no-scripts and I got  Failed to download voku/portable-ascii from dist: Could not delete C:\Users\Admin\Budget/vendor/composer/4a8c9861\voku-portable-ascii-618631d\src\voku\helper\data:
This can be due to an antivirus or the Windows Search Indexer locking the file while they are analyzed
    Now trying to download from source

Comment: @HillaryOkello go to your composer.json and delete or comment or voku-portable-ASCII line and Try again with composer update — no scripts

Comment: I have done it and now am getting server error in the browser after running php artisan serve

Comment: What is the server error can you please mention that too ? Also have you done migration after which you are having this issue.